# Override method in a non Activity class, Android

Tags: java, android, overriding

I'm working on an app which uses default Camera app for taking a photo. Now I want to check is there were taken the photo.

I read on SO that that could be done with this method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  ...
    }
```

My problem is when I put that method in my class which isnt an Activity class I got error:

*"The method onActivityResult(..) must override or implement a supertype method"*

I already check, my compiler is set to java 1.6. and my jre is set to 1.6.

What should I do?

Comment: Well no, you can't override a method from one class (Activity) in a class which isn't a subclass of that class. What would that even mean?

Comment: `onActivityResult()` is a method in the class `Activity`. Therefore if you're not extending `Activity`, you can't override it.

Comment: Put that method in your Activity class.  When you return from the camera app it will be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `Activity` on order to receive the result of the camera action.  Why do you want to put the code in some other class?  If it is just for re-use/organisation then why not just call your other class from your `Activity`?

```
public class SomeOtherClass {
    public static void someOtherMethod(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        ...
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    SomeOtherClass.someOtherMethod(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I decided ti implement. Its good enough. Thank you. @Benoît Bouré result is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can only get the result from an Activity inside another Activity or Fragment.
Therefore you can only extend onActivityResult() from a class that extends Activity or one of it's descendants (This is actually java-related and not android-related).
Also, you must extend and define onActivityResult() in the same activity where you call startActivityForResult().

If you need to execute code in another class that does not extend Activity, you can simply implement your own method and call it from inside onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
   {
     MyClass object = new MyClass(); //or maybe it's already instantiated and it is defined as a field
     object.myCustomMethod(data); //pass it data or one of it's extras
   }

}
```

Comment: This solution is also good enough. Thank you. @dave.c result is also correct.